# JsonGenerationException: CSV generator does not support Object values for properties

Tags: java, csv, serialization, jackson, jackson-modules

I'm trying to serialize `Foo` into a `String`. It seems like a pretty simple task but for some reason `DateTime` seems to break it.

**Test.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setID(1);
            foo.setCURRENT(new DateTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())));
            foos.add(foo);
            String content = serialize(foos, Foo.class, Boolean.TRUE);
            System.out.println(content);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static final synchronized String serialize(final Object object, final Class type, final Boolean withHeaders) throws IOException {
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema csvSchema;
        if (withHeaders) {
            csvSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(type).withHeader();
        } else {
            csvSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(type).withoutHeader();
        }
        return csvMapper.writer(csvSchema).writeValueAsString(object);
    }

}
```

**Foo.java**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Foo {

    private Integer ID;
    private DateTime CURRENT;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Integer ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public DateTime getCURRENT() {
        return CURRENT;
    }

    public void setCURRENT(DateTime CURRENT) {
        this.CURRENT = CURRENT;
    }

}
```

I've tried using `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter` in my `Foo` object but it doesn't really make any impact.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including datatype module for Joda `DateTime`? The one you need is `jackson-datatype-joda`, from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda. If not, that would explain the issue, since values would be seen as regular POJOs, and CSV is not good for nested data without some sort of mapping to dotted notation.